# Using Entity Framework 4.1, how can I achive below requirement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider I have 2 entities - a) Publisher b) Book
Publisher has navigation property called as PublishedBooks which is collection of Books.
Assume that Publisher1 has published 2 books ie Book1 & Book2
What I would like to do is, for a Publisher1, delete published book Book1 and 
add a new published book (ie Book3), in the database.

Context.SaveChanges() throwing below error -

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

Note : Delete cascade rule is present in database as well as in the context class.
BTW, I am using C# & Sql Server 2005.

Comment: // I am trying to remove the book from the Publisher's book collection as - 
Publiser1.Books.Remove(Publisher1.Books.First()); 
// then add a new book to the same collection as -
var newbook = new book(){};
Publiser1.Books.Add(newbook);
Context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Thanks but please add the code to your question. Also show the Book and Publisher class so other people know how you have implemented it currently. So they can correct you if you have some mistakes in the code ;)

Comment: sure will create a poc and upload it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing something like this:

```
Foo foo = entity.RelatedFoos.Where(f=>f.id=xyz);
entity.RelatedFoos.Remove(foo); //this is the problematic line
context.SaveChanges();
```

That is; you are removing an entity from a set of related items - not from the main collection on the context itself. As noted in the error, removing the above way only removes the *relation*. Not the object `foo`. This is probably what you meant, if you mean to delete the `foo`:

```
Foo foo = entity.RelatedFoos.Where(f=>f.id=xyz);
context.Foos.Remove(foo);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: hmm understood now. Instead of removing the object from entity, remove it from db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly delete the child object before the save, e.g.

```
Context.DeleteObject(Book1);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am yet to test your suggestion but seems that it will work. See my comments in response to 'hwcverwe'. So that you will get better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I see, I think the DeleteObject method should work in your scenario.  The Remove disconnects it but it allows that you might want to do something else with it such as attaching to another Publisher.